# How to change the arrows up or down depending on the sorting?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to change the arrows depending on the sort, like [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/sorting).

sortingPipe.ts:

```
import { SprBitType } from '../spr-bit-type/sprBitType'; 
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortingSprBitType'
})

export class SortingSprBitTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(sprBitTypes: SprBitType[], path: string[], order: number = 1): SprBitType[] {
    // Check if is not null
    if (!sprBitTypes || !path || !order) return sprBitTypes;
    return sprBitTypes.sort((a: SprBitType, b: SprBitType) => {
      // We go for each property followed by path
      path.forEach(property => {
        a = a[property];
        b = b[property];
      })
      // Order * (-1): We change our order
      return a > b ? order : order * (- 1);
    })
  }
}
```

sortingPipe.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SortingSprBitTypePipe } from './sortingSprBitType.pipe';

describe('SortingSprBitTypePipe', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    const pipe = new SortingSprBitTypePipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Component.ts:

```
...
  path: string[] = ['sprBitType'];
  order: number = 1; // 1 asc, -1 desc;

...

  sortTable(prop: string) {
    this.path = prop.split('.')
    this.order = this.order * (-1); // change order
    return false; // do not reload
  }

...
```

Here is how html can be more properly remade (using these symbols for the ordering of ▲ ▼):

```
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortTable('name')" >Name⬍</a>
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortTable('rn')"> RN⬍</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing it is using `*ngIF` that will depend on `order` const.

so your HTML will look like this

```
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortTable('name')" >
    Name
    <label *ngIf="orderByName === 1">▲</label>
    <label *ngIf="orderByName === -1">▼</label>
</a>
<a class="sorting" (click)="sortTable('rn')"> 
    RN
    <label *ngIf="orderByRn === 1">▲</label>
    <label *ngIf="orderByRn === -1">▼</label>
</a>
```

And in your Component.ts file have this

```
...

path: string[] = ['sprBitType'];
order: number = 1; // 1 asc, -1 desc;
orderByName: 1; // Guessing that asc is default
orderByRn: 1 // Guessing that asc is default

...

sortTable(prop: string) {
    this.path = prop.split('.')
    this.order = this.order * (-1); // change order
    if(prop == name){
        this.orderByName = this.order;
    }
    if(prop == rn){
        this,orderByName = this.order;
    }
    return false; // do not reload
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but "Type "number" can not be assigned for type "1"".    
Screenshot: https://radikal.ru/lfp/a.radikal.ru/a07/1802/49/e63dcfefb3e3.png/htm

Comment: Try setting `orderByName` to `orderByName: this.order` same with `orderByRn`